# docker in docker without privileged mode

Tags: security, virtualization, docker, performance-tuning

Last time I used docker in docker for runners, but **it requires privileged mode**

compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - ./run:/var/run/
#      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  docker:
    image: docker:dind
    restart: always
    privileged: true # <-- security problems
    volumes:
      - ./run:/var/run/
```

I have a personal PC. I have a Gitlab team that needs to run `docker build` or `docker-compose up` scripts with Gitlab CI. I really want to speed up CI. That is why I share my *host* docker with *runners*, now they have docker cache (images, and so on) and when one stage build image and another one require it is really fast.

I have the same problem with Jenkins. I need to share host docker with worker nodes.

Last time I wanted to test the new approach and run runners with their own docker. I almost don't have 2 important things:
 - resource limit (I want to share 7 of 8 CPU cores, 10 of 16 GB memory, some HDD limits)
 - security

It is important to add: I don't have CI scripts that require GPU, network capabilities, mounting some devices and so on. They usually do simple `docker build` and `docker push`, sometimes I need to grab artifacts with `docker cp`, that is all.
Main question: how to **run docker in docker without root privileges to host machine**?

Both - socket sharing or privileged mode give vulnerabilities to host machines, and have a virtual machine (like VirtualBox or something) is slow and hard to do, also I want to share resources, and want that docker *can* use 10 of 16 GB, but 10 GB should be free when it doesn't use it.

I have some non-informative errors from dind contatiner (before fail) when I run it with usual priviliges:

```
gitlab-runner-docker | mount: permission denied (are you root?)
gitlab-runner-docker | mount: permission denied (are you root?)
gitlab-runner-docker | Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
gitlab-runner-docker | AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
```

What problems I will have if try to run docker in docker without privileged mode? How to do it?

Comment: "What problems I will have if try to run docker in docker without privileged mode?" It won't work. You won't be able to build images or run containers.

Answer (score 0):

well, regarding the load balancing of the ram memory, I can't help but you can run a docker in docker (dind) without sudo permissions by adding your current user to the docker group,

I don't see the security of the shared sockets because it loses its integrity but I would recommend instantiating the dind with the parameter the composer with the privileged parameter: true